# How to set default values to SCSS variables?

Tags: css, sass

I am building a template using SCSS and Shopify Liquid.

I am trying to set a customisable primary colour with a default, incase a value has not been set, like so:

```
$primaryColour: {{ settings.color_primary }} ||= #f02222;
```

See if a variable has not been defined anything, a SCSS error occurs. I could just set a default value in the Shopify settings, or use the `default` filter like so:

```
$primaryColour: {{ settings.color_primary | default: '#f02222' }};
```

But for terms and purposes, I would still like to know how, because if I do not do that, it prints out as:

```
$primaryColour: ;
```

...creating an error.

Comment: Not sure that duplicate answers what happens when the variable prints out as `$primaryColour: ;`, due to the use of Shopify Liquid

Comment: Plus, I am not assigning a variable with another variable